# Tomcat virtual Host

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I have an application hosted on a server. I want all small customers to share a virtual host and I want setup a dedicated virtual host for each big customer. the applications are totally same, can I have the virtual point to the same codebase directory?

I am using Tomcat 7 as application server, please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it always is the same app they are using, you can try this. Otherwise change the appBase, i.e. for a regular customer (server.xml):

```
<Host name="smallCustomers.com" appBase="webapps" ...>
  ...
</Host>

<Host name="regularCustomer1.com" appBase="webapps" ...>
  ...
</Host>

<Host name="regularCustomer2.com" appBase="webapps" ...>
  ...
</Host>
```

Comment: I have done it this way as well. In my case I had to create an A record in DNS so all the sub-domains point to the right place.