# How to map different Tomcat 9 applications to different URLs?

Tags: tomcat9

I have a Tomcat 9 server with two applications installed on it: "App1" and "App2". Obviously, these applications are accessible using these two URLs:

http://my_xyz.com/App1

http://my_xyz.com/App2

I need to be able to access the first application using the URL:

http://other_xyz.com/

and the second application using:

http://yet_xyz.com/

It is required **NOT** to use a web server in front of it. Only the Tomcat 9 server should be configured.

Remark that "App1" and "App2" does not appear in the new URLs. Tomcat virtual hosts is the solution, but how can I hide the applications names?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814449/tomcat-virtual-host)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Well, not really. The problem is in the last line: I need to hide the names of the applications "App1" and "App2". I know that I need Tomcat Virtual Hosts, but how can I hide the applications name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you remark in your post you just need to:

1. create two virtual hosts:

```xml
<Host name="app1.example.com" docBase="webapps/app1.example.com">
    ...
</Host>
<Host name="app2.example.com" docBase="webapps/app2.example.com">
    ...
</Host>
```

2. Once the virtual hosts are configured, you can independently add applications to each one of them. Most importantly you can have two applications with an empty context path (one for each host). E.g. you can move the WAR file of the first application to `webapps/app1.example.com/ROOT.war` and the second one to `webapps/app2.example.com/ROOT.war` (or use any of the [other ways to deploy an application](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup)).